# Why apache config Define Directive not work correct inside If, ElseIf, Else?

Tags: apache

I am use Apache 2.4.37

I was surprised to find myself, that Define Directive not work correct inside [≶If>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if) [≶ElseIf>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#elseif) [≶Else>](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#else) Directives. In this sample the sSection will be "section2", ie even if -d is equal "/www/section1/%{HTTP_HOST}/www". Always triggerd the last Define Directive from the list.

```
…
<If "-d '/www/section1/%{HTTP_HOST}/www'">
   Define sSection section1
</If>
<If "-d '/www/section2/%{HTTP_HOST}/www'">
   Define sSection section2
</If>

UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /www/${sSection}/%0/www
…
```

Example above is equivalent to:

```
…
Define sSection section1
Define sSection section2

UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /www/${sSection}/%0/www
…
```

What can be wrong?

How, besides the Define Directive, can we define variables inside the Apache config?

Comment: Maybe by accident both directories exist? I mean, if both `if` are true, the last one will override the others.

Comment: Of course not. I killed 2 days to try to resolve the issue. Everything is tested. Last hope is community.

Comment: Yup, still doesn't work. I wanted to implement PHP version select based on cookies and hit the same bug.